# Teraform: Filter a map using a list of keys to create a new map

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform map object that looks like this

```
all_subnets = {
    "10.1.1.1/24"  = "subnet-a"
    "10.2.2.2/24" = "subnet-b"
    "10.3.3.3/24"  = "subnet-c"
    "10.4.4.4/24" = "subnet-d"
  }
```

I then have a terrafrom list object that looks like this

```
subnets_i_like = ["10.1.1.1/24","10.4.4.4/24"]
```

I want to iterate through this `subnets_i_like` list and filter out only the elements  in the `all_subnets` map where the list element matches the map key ... and create a new map, resulting in a new map that looks like this

```
new_map = {
    "10.1.1.1/24"  = "subnet-a"
    "10.4.4.4/24" = "subnet-d"
  }
```

Does anyone know how I would tackle this? I havent been able to find an example of this use case to guide me...Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the `contains` function with a conditional inside a `for` expression inside a `map` constructor for this:

```
{ for ip, subnet in local.all_subnets : ip => subnet if contains(local.subnets_i_like, ip) }
```

As the scopes for `all_subnets` and `subnets_i_like` were not provided in the question the `locals` scope was assumed in the answer. Please update according to the actual scope(s) of the variables.

Comment: Thank you, that has worked for me..The variables are indeed Locals